# SQL Server Hekaton Reclaim Memory Used by Dropped Memory-Optimized Tables

Tags: sql-server, out-of-memory, memory-optimized-tables

I'm using

> Microsoft SQL Server Enterprise: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) Version
>   12.0.4100.1

I have a code which creates many non-durable memory-optimized tables, uses them for some things, and drops them when it doesn't need them anymore.

However, it seems as though the dropped tables are still consuming RAM, since if I run

```
SELECT pool_id, Name, min_memory_percent, max_memory_percent, max_memory_kb/1024 AS max_memory_mb, 
    used_memory_kb/1024 AS used_memory_mb, target_memory_kb/1024 AS target_memory_mb  
FROM sys.dm_resource_governor_resource_pools 
WHERE Name='InMemoryObjects'
```

I get the following:

```
pool_id  Name                min_memory_percent max_memory_percent  max_memory_mb   used_memory_mb  target_memory_mb
256      InMemoryObjects     50                 50                  380003          233239          380003
```

Notice how high the "used_memory_mb" column is.  There are no memory-optimized tables in the server at the time I ran this, so I figure it must be data from the dropped memory-optimized tables still somehow taking up RAM.

Similarly, when I run

```
SELECT type, name, memory_node_id, pages_kb/1024 AS pages_MB   
FROM sys.dm_os_memory_clerks WHERE type LIKE '%xtp%'
```

I get the following output:

```
type            name        memory_node_id  pages_MB
MEMORYCLERK_XTP Default     0               1055
MEMORYCLERK_XTP DB_ID_19    0               6
MEMORYCLERK_XTP DB_ID_33    0               6
MEMORYCLERK_XTP DB_ID_41    0               56
MEMORYCLERK_XTP DB_ID_47    0               0
MEMORYCLERK_XTP DB_ID_32    0               233240
MEMORYCLERK_XTP Default     1               0
MEMORYCLERK_XTP Default     64              0
```

See how DB_ID_32 is taking up the same ~240gb of RAM?

I need some way to clear this out.  When I run more than one instance of the code, I get the error 
"There is insufficient system memory in resource pool 'InMemoryObjects' to run this query".  So I think this memory has to actually be tied up, and doesn't release itself when it gets full.  The resource pool 'InMemoryObjects' was made just for this one code, and there are no other memory-optimized objects in the entire server besides the ones this code creates (and subsequently drops).  The memory-optimized tables it creates are all reasonably small (a few gb apiece).

I know the garbage collector is supposed to run every minute, but it has been over a day since any memory-optimized tables have existed in the database, and the memory used hasn't decreased at all.  I've tried forcing garbage collection, checkpoints, resetting statistics, etc., and haven't been able to get this memory back.

The only thing I've found that works is taking the entire database offline and bringing it back online.  But I really can't do that each time I run the code, so I need a better solution.

Any ideas would be immensely appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: Are you taking regular log backups?

Comment: I'm not manually taking any log backups.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be a reason. But I'm surprised the forced garbage collection doesn't pick it up. From the MSDN documentation on the in-memory garbage collection:

> After a user transaction commits, it identifies all queued items
>   associated with the scheduler it ran on and then releases the memory.
>   If the garbage collection queue on the scheduler is empty, it searches
>   for any non-empty queue in the current NUMA node. If there is low
>   transactional activity and there is memory pressure, the main
>   garbage-collection thread can access garbage collect rows from any
>   queue. ***If there is no transactional activity after (for example)
>   deleting a large number of rows and there is no memory pressure, the
>   deleted rows will not be garbage collected until the transactional
>   activity resumes or there is memory pressure.***

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn643768.aspx

Might try the filestream garbage collection? I think I read somewhere that the in-memory optimized filegroup that a db must have uses the filestream technology. Don't quote me on that.

Comment: I appreciate the input.  I've read that same documentation, but A) there is clearly memory pressure, since I can sometimes get the "There is insufficient system memory in resource pool 'InMemoryObjects' to run this query" error, and B) There is still plenty of transactional activity (since the code goes on to create and delete many other tables).  I have also already tried the force filestream collection with no luck.

Comment: When I look at sys.dm_xtp_gc_queue_stats, 22 of the 64 queue_id's have a nonzero "current_queue_depth", indicating they're still in garbage collection queue (I think).  Most of these 22 current_queue_depths are 59136 or 59137 (but I'm honestly not sure what these numbers mean).

Comment: A current queue depth means there is GC work to do, but it has not yet been done. Multiply that number by 16 to get the number of rows queued for GC. I am currently working on a similar issue where the XTP clerks grow and start starving the buffer pool, even though we only use memory optimized table variables. What are the stats on this box? If I had to guess I would say its a 16 core/768gb of memory?